# If $\varphi$ is irreducible as representation over the algebraic numbers, then $\varphi$ is irreducible as a complex representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $F\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be the subfield of algebraic numbers. Then a representation $\varphi\colon G\to GL_m(F)$ of a finite group $G$ may be also viewed as a complex representation.

If $\varphi\colon G\to GL_m(F)$ is irreducible over $F$, why is it also irreducible when considered over $\mathbb{C}$?

I think these representations are respectively afforded by  $F^m$ and $\mathbb{C}^m$, both with   with the $FG$- and $\mathbb{C}G$-module structure given by $g\cdot v=\varphi(g)(v)$. Towards a contradiction, I was supposing if $\mathbb{C}^m=N\oplus P$ is reducible, then this somehow induces a nontrivial decomposition of $F^m$. Since $N$ is $G$-stable, then so is $N\cap F^m$, so by irreducibility, $N\cap F^m=0$ or $N\cap F^m=F^m$? If $N\cap F^m=0$, then every nonzero vector of $N$ has a transcendental coordinate, and if $N\cap F^m=F^m$, then every nonzero vector of $P$ has a transcendental coordinate. I'm trying to find a contradiction, but I'm not sure if this is the right track.

This comes from Dummit and Foote, 18.3.14.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to see this is to "turn it around". Let $\pi:G\rightarrow Aut_\Bbb{Q}(V)$ be an irreducible $\Bbb{Q}$-representation of $G$. There exists a finite (algebraic) extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ (so $K\subset F$) called the *splitting field* of $G$ such that all representations over larger fields $L\supset K$ are equivalent to a $K$-representation (via extension/restriction of scalars, and moving between fields of definition in this way preserves irreducibility).

The point of this is that if we take an irreducible complex representation $V$ of $G$, this is equivalent to an irreducible representation $W$ of $G$ over its splitting field $E$, and one has $V=W\otimes_E\Bbb{C}$. As $E\subset F\subset\Bbb{C}$, the restriction of scalars of $V$ to $F$ must certainly be irreducible.

Comment: Thanks PL. I haven't read about splitting fields of groups yet, but hopefully this will make more sense to me later on.